# How to instruct g++ to stop after n seconds

Tags: c++, g++, flags

I was wondering, if there is any flag option in `g++` to limit runtime, like stack-size `-stack_size = any_limit` and the number of errors, `-fmax-errors=n`. Say I want to halt the execution after `20 seconds` then, other than adding a `while` loop can I use any flag which performs the same action.

Comment: [timeout](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) might be of interest...

Comment: or `(ulimit -t 20 ; gcc ...)`

Comment: @JonathanWakely How does that work? Seems to be a command, but it didn't kill the `sleep` I tried, `(ulimit -t 1; sleep 20)`

Comment: `ulimit -t 1` is limiting the *CPU* time, and `sleep` does not eat any CPU time!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is confusing.

The [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler is mostly CPU bound. So if you want to limit the compilation time, use `ulimit -t 20;` then the next `g++` command would get killed (with `SIGXCPU`) after 20 seconds of CPU time (see also [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)...). But 20 seconds of compile time is a big lot.

You might consider [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) with [developer options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) such as `-ftime-report`, and you could extend GCC with your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) limiting more precisely the compilation time. Since GCC is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), you could even patch it for your needs (read about its [pass manager](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Pass-manager.html)). With such an approach, budget perhaps a week or a few months of work.

But if you are asking about how to ask the `g++` compiler to magically limit the execution time (or run time) of the generated executable, it is not the business of the compiler.

A possibility might be to add, inside the C++ code of your program, at *some* points, a test about current timeout. IIRC, the [*Parma Polyhedra Library*](https://www.bugseng.com/parma-polyhedra-library) is doing so. You could BTW use a preprocessor such as [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) to generate such C++ code. You might use [setitimer(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html) with your signal handler (read [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)) setting some `volatile sigatomic_t timedout;` variable, which would be tested by e.g. some macro such as

```
#define TEST_TIMEOUT() do { if (timedout) handle_timeout(); } while(0)
```

then you would put `TEST_TIMEOUT()` at appropriate places in your C++ code. Jacques Pitrat's last book [*artificial beings : the conscience of a conscious machine*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848211015) is suggesting such an approach.

Your C++ application (perhaps coded with [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)) might also have some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). Then see also [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [timerfd_create(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html), [signalfd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) and the [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) to self trick documented in [*Calling Qt Functions From Unix Signal Handlers*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html)

Read [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) which is the system call invoked by the [`ulimit` Bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html).

Regarding timing in general, read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). In your particular C++ code, you might be interested in using [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) or [alarm(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html) (and you could call  [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) near the beginning).

See also [timeout(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html).

Be also aware of the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) and [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).